# Web Service Not Running in onbeforeunload for reload

Tags: javascript, web-services, ajax.net

I have an onbeforeunload method that calls a web service method. It works great when I click on a link to another page, but when I reload the page, the onbeforeunload method runs and it processes the web service call on the client side as normal, but it never actually reaches the web service on the server side.

If I put an alert message after the call, then it works. So it appears that the page unloads so fast that the web service doesn't get called.

How can I make sure the web service gets called without the alert?

```
function pageUnload_ProcessLayout(sender, args){        
        webservice.removeHolder(Global.currUser.UserId, function(result){ });
        alert(2);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does it help if you put call to `webservice.removeHolder` into a short setTimeout?

Comment: You mean something like this:


    function pageUnload_ProcessLayout(sender, args){        
        setTimeout("unloadTimeout()", 30);
    }

    function unloadTimeout(){
        webservice.removeHolder(Global.currUser.UserId, function(result){ });
    }


That doesn't work.

Comment: Then u may have to call the service synchronously - if you want the page unload to wait for it to finish. This goes against the grain, but if the service doesn't take too long to execute it may work for u. Take a look at this http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/calling-web-service-methods-synchronously-in-asp-net-ajax